# How to pass variable by reference in Invoke-Command -ArgumentList

Tags: powershell, pass-by-reference

```
$re = 0
Invoke-Command $server {
    #param([ref]$r)
    ...
    $r = 1
} -ArgumentList [ref]$re
```

I want to pass in $re and modify its value in the {}. What is correct syntax to achieve this? Above code emits error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass your var by ref, just assign the result of icm to $re :

```
$re = 0
$re=icm -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock{param($r) $r+1} -ArgumentList $re    
$re
```

with PS version >=3 you can do

```
$re=icm -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock{$using:re +1}
```

BTW `{}` is called a script block

Comment: this does not change local variable value